# Convert dataframe into a structure list in R

Tags: r

Given a dataset as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("a","a","b","b"), B=c("X","X","Y","Z"), C=c(1,2,3,4))
```

How could I convert it into a structure list similarly as follows in R?

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(14699, 14790, 14882, 14974, 
15064, 15155, 15247, 15339, 15430, 15521, 15613, 15705, 15795, 
15886, 15978, 16070, 16160, 16251, 16343, 16435, 16525, 16616, 
16708, 16800, 16891, 16982, 17074, 17166, 17256, 17347, 17439, 
17531, 17621, 17712, 17804, 17896, 17986, 18077, 18169, 18261, 
18352, 18443), class = "Date"), value = c(12.2, 11.4, 10.9, 10.6, 
10.2, 10.1, 9.9, 9.6, 8.1, 7.9, 7.8, 7.9, 7.9, 7.7, 7.8, 7.8, 
7.5, 7.6, 7.5, 7.4, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 7, 6.9, 6.9, 6.8, 6.8, 7, 
7, 7, 6.9, 6.9, 6.9, 6.8, 6.7, 6.4, 6.3, 6.2, 6.1, -6.8, 3.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-42L))
```

Comment: You mean `dput(df)`? It's quite unclear what you're aiming at...

Comment: Yes, that's it, I forgot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code we need to use:

```
dput(df)
```